# UnicodeDecodeError when using json.dumps on full object, works fine when only printing specific property

Tags: python, json, unicode

I'm getting a UnicodeDecodeError when I try to use json.dumps on the following object:

```
testObject = {'crs': {'wkid': 4326, 'wkt': 'WGS84'}, 'candidates': [{'score': 200, 'type': 'ADR', 'location': {'y': 50.2485465358886, 'x': 4.38243469412172, 'crs': {'wkid': 4326, 'wkt': 'WGS84'}}, 'address': {'city': 'Fontenelle', 'munkey': '0585'}}, {'score': 200, 'type': 'ADR', 'location': {'y': 50.4123146893214, 'x': 4.32436581556278, 'crs': {'wkid': 4326, 'wkt': 'WGS84'}}, 'address': {'city': "Fontaine-l'\\xe3\\x89v\\xe3\\xaaque", 'munkey': '0324'}}, {'score': 200, 'type': 'ADR', 'location': {'y': 50.3217667573625, 'x': 4.21386030471998, 'crs': {'wkid': 4326, 'wkt': 'WGS84'}}, 'address': {'city': 'Fontaine-valmont', 'munkey': '0362'}}, {'score': 200, 'type': 'ADR', 'location': {'y': 49.7151404477129, 'x': 5.23438436377951, 'crs': {'wkid': 4326, 'wkt': 'WGS84'}}, 'address': {'city': 'Fontenoille', 'munkey': '0541'}}], 'id': u'1', 'address': {'city': u'Fontaine-lev', 'street': u'Avenue des Chones', 'zone': u'1301', 'house': u'19'}}
print json.dumps(testObject, False, False)
```

The error message is the following:

```
UnicodeDecodeError('ascii', '"Fontaine-l\\'\\xe3\\x89v\\xe3\\xaaque"', 12, 13, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It seems like there is something wrong with the encoding of the characters in this string. This string is being fetched through a psycopg2 connector with encoding 'utf8' making a postgresql DB request. The actual value should be "Fontaine l'Evêque".

What is really strange though, is that when I loop over the 'candidates' property of this object, and do a json.dumps of each candidate, it does not crash:

```
for c in testObject.candidates:
  print json.dumps(c, False, False)
```

result:

```
{'score': 200, 'type': 'ADR', 'location': {'y': 50.4123146893214, 'x': 4.32436581556278, 'crs': {'wkid': 4326, 'wkt': 'WGS84'}}, 'address': {'city': "Fontaine-l'\\xe3\\x89v\\xe3\\xaaque", 'munkey': '0324'}}
```

As you can see, the string in question is exactly the same. Why does json.dumps work fine when only dumping the single candidate, but all of a sudden it cannot decode the same string when I'm trying to dump the whole object?

Edit: I simplified the code to provide above example, but apparently this works fine. Here is my actual code:

```
for search in searches:
  print "search: ", search
  searchCrash = {'score': 200, 'type': 'ADR', 'location': {'y': 50.4123146893214, 'x': 4.32436581556278, 'crs': {'wkid': 4326, 'wkt': 'WGS84'}}, 'address': {'city': "Fontaine-l'\\xe3\\x89v\\xe3\\xaaque", 'munkey': '0324'}}
  print "searchCrash: ", json.dumps(searchCrash, False, False)
  print "dump search: ", json.dumps(search, False, False)
```

I get the following:

```
search: {'score': 200, 'type': 'ADR', 'location': {'y': 50.4123146893214, 'x': 4.32436581556278, 'crs': {'wkid': 4326, 'wkt': 'WGS84'}}, 'address': {'city': "Fontaine-l'\\xe3\\x89v\\xe3\\xaaque", 'munkey': '0324'}}
searchCrash: {'score': 200, 'type': 'ADR', 'location': {'y': 50.4123146893214, 'x': 4.32436581556278, 'crs': {'wkid': 4326, 'wkt': 'WGS84'}}, 'address': {'city': "Fontaine-l'\\xe3\\x89v\\xe3\\xaaque", 'munkey': '0324'}}
dump search: UnicodeDecodeError('ascii', '"Fontaine-l\\'\\xe3\\x89v\\xe3\\xaaque"', 12, 13, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
    'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So I pretty much just print search to see what is inside. I copy paste the result of this print into a variable and json.dumps it, which works fine, yet when I use json.dumps on the actual search it fails with the unicode error.

Comment: What is `x.toDict()` ?

Comment: It's clear you are not using Python 3, so I pasted the code you posted into a Python 2.7 interpreter. That works. The non-ascii characters are escaped with `\x`.

Comment: @Maurice Meyer Oh, this is some old leftover code. Not relevant anymore, I removed it from my OP.

Comment: @BoarGules I simplified my code for this example, I notice that indeed it does work. Please see my edit. If I print the variable and assign the result of this print to a variable and json.dumps it, it works fine, yet if I do the json.dumps directly on it, it will crash with the unicode error. Pretty strange..

Comment: One problem is `"Fontaine-l'\\xe3\\x89v\\xe3\\xaaque"` is some mojibake for `u"Fontaine-l'Évêque"` (via Google Earth and the lat/long coords).  That's not UTF-8 or any other encoding I could figure out.  Your data is corrupt.  `json` takes Unicode strings as input.  If you give it a messed up byte string, Python 2 wil implicitly convert it to Unicode with the `ascii` codec, hence the error.